# Reading a list of names from a text File into a 2D array

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to read a column of names from a text file into a two dimensional array, the names vary in length but are at max 8 letters long, and there are 10 of them. Here are my two for loops to read the names and then to print them.

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j != 8; j++) {
        infile >> textfileinfo[i][j];
    }
}
```

and then to print the names out I have this loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j != 8; j++) {
        cout << textfileinfo[i][j];
    }
    cout << " " << endl;
}
```

Here is the list of names:

```
Victor
Eve
Juliet
Hector
Danielle
Romeo
Oscar
June
Ares
Dannae
```

What ends up happening is it will read the names out with 8 characters regardless, taking the extra characters from the next name, so `Victor` turns into `VictorEv`, then `eJulietH` and so on. How do I get it to start on the next row once the end of Victor is reached, and then move on to Eve etc. I am not allowed to use pointers either. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why is this a 2D array instead of `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: @drescherjm The guidelines for the assignment say we have to read it into a 2D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the obvious thing is to use `getline`. `getline` is designed to read a single line of text.

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
     infile.getline(textfileinfo[i], 9);
}
```

Note that the second argument to getline is 9 because you need an extra character to store the nul terminator that ends every C style string. This also mean that your 2D array need to be declared with at least 9 characters in each row. Slightly safer code would be to make this explicit

```
infile.getline(textfileinfo[i], sizeof textfileinfo[i]);
```

If for some reason you aren't allowed to use `getline` then you going to have to modify your inner loop to detect and deal with the `'\n'` character that terminates every line.

Comment: Yea we can't use the `<string>` header either sadly, so I will just have to modify it, any suggestions on how to go about that?

Comment: The code above does not require the `<string>` header

Comment: Ah ok, I was made an error, It's working now! Thanks!